# what is the best way to get a portion of this url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I am creating like a link like so:

```
<%= link_to('', "#{issueable}/#{order.id}/issues" %>
```

which creates a link like this:

> ***root***/version2/parts/2418/issues

I want to be able to get the "parts" (/version2/**parts**/2418/issues) portion of that url when the user clicks the link to that controller method.

Comment: So you want to get `2418` from `root/version2/parts/2418/issues` ?

Comment: Sorry, no I want the string "parts". I'll make that more clear.

Comment: Something [like this](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/07590)?

Comment: works for me. Thanks! Make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-split):

```
link = "root/version2/parts/2418/issues"
puts link.split('/')[2].strip
#outputs parts 

link = "version2/parts/2418"
puts link.split('/')[1].strip
#outputs parts
```

[Ruby fiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/07590)

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you've got a string `"/version2/parts/2418/issues"` and you want to extract the `'parts'` position from it.

```
"/version2/parts/2418/issues".split('/')[-3]
```

You'll need to figure out yourself whether to get [2] from the split array or [-3]. As an added '/' in the beginning or in the end could mess it up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex assuming you know that it starts with "version2" and also know the order_id when it gets to it.

```
"/version2/parts/2418/issues".match(/\/version2\/(\w+)\/2418/)
puts $1
```